# Exception in thread "main" IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 0

Tags: java, arraylist, array-bidimensional

Tengo el siguiente problema:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmQUx.jpg , https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLNTk.jpg

Se crea un ArrayList numérico entero bidimensional. Tiene un número de filas escrita por el usuario, sólo se aceptan valores entre 2 y 5, ambos inclusive. Tiene un número de columnas aleatorio en cada fila entre 3 y 9, ambos inclusive. Distintas filas pueden tener distinto número de columnas. Cada celda tiene un valor aleatorio entre -10 y 10, ambos inclusive.

Lo tengo todo bien pero me dice que me salgo de rango, como podría solucionarlo?

El error esta en

> setMatriz()

Aquí dejo el código:

```
package e2.Ej4;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Escribir 
{   public static FileOutputStream Esc= null;
    static Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static XSSFWorkbook WK = null;
    public static XSSFSheet H1 = null;
    
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> Números = new ArrayList <>();
    public static short nf, nc;
    
    public static void setXSSFWorkbook()
    {   WK = new  XSSFWorkbook();
    }
    
    public static void setXSSFSheet()
    {   H1 = WK.createSheet("H1");
    }
    
    public static void setFilasColumnas()
    {   short minC = 3, maxC = 9;
        do
        {   System.out.print("Introduzca número de filas (entre 2 y 5): ");
            nf = Short.valueOf(Sc.nextLine());
        }while(! (nf>=2) && (nf<=5));
        
        do
        {   nc = (short) (minC + (Math.random()*(maxC-minC+1)));
        }while(! (nc>=3) && (nc<=9));
    }
    
    public static void setNúmeroColumnas()
    {   for (byte c=0;c<nc;c++)
            Números.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    
    public static void setMatriz()
    {   int min = -10, max = 10, ale = (short)(min+(Math.random()*(max-min+1)));
        for(int f=2; f<nf; f++)
        {   for(int c=3; c<nc; c++)
            {   Números.get(f).add(c, ale);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void setDatos()
    {   for(int f=2; f<nf; f++)
        {   Iterator itC = Números.get(f).iterator();
            XSSFRow filas = H1.createRow(f);
            for(int c=3; c<nc; c++)
            {   while (itC.hasNext())
                {   String txt = itC.next()+"";
                    XSSFCell columnas = filas.createCell(c);
                    columnas.setCellValue(txt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    /*public static void setDatos()
    {   for(int f=2; f<nf; f++)
        {   XSSFRow filas = H1.createRow(f);
            //Números.get(f);
            for(int c=3; c<nc; c++)
            {   XSSFCell columnas = filas.createCell(c);
                String txt = (Números.get(c))+"";
                columnas.setCellValue(txt);
            }
        }
    }*/
    
    public static void setFlujo()
    {   try
        {   Esc = new FileOutputStream("Numeros.xlsx");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void Enviar()
    {   try
        {   WK.write(Esc);
            Esc.flush();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void Cerrar()
    {   try
        {   Esc.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y tanto que te sales de rango. Estás intentando coger el elemento 2  (el tercero, teniendo en cuenta que empezamos los array en 0) y no tienes ninguno aun en la lista... De hecho, eso es exactamente lo que dice tu error, intentas coger el índice 3 y tienes 0 elementos en la lista! No puedes hacer `Números.get(f).add(c, ale)`, si f vale 2 y tienes 0 elementos!

Comment: Por cierto... deberías añadir el código relacionado. Que nos enseñes métodos que no llamas no nos dice absolutamente nada, pero que no nos enseñes en qué orden llamas a los métodos hace que no podamos ver el problema exacto. Por otro lado, ***JAMÁS*** se deben escribir nombres de métodos ( o variables) así: `setNúmeroColumnas`, los acentos están bien cuando escribimos en español, pero en lenguajes de programación no hacen más que dar problemas!

Comment: muchas gracias, recien estaba empezando con la programacion y no tenia mucha vision funcional, siento responderte tarde, pero lo vi ahora, igualmente ya soluciones el error, gracias por dedicarme tu tiempo